# Subscribe to all current and future items in array

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular5

Using RxJS with Angular5, I have a service that contains an array.
Some components will get created / destroyed / re-created, as the array is being populated.

So we have a service like so:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
   public events = [];
}
```

then we have a component like so:

```
@Inject(MyService)
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

  mySub: Subscriber

  constructor(private ms: MyService){}

  ngOnInit(){

   this.mySub = Rx.Observable.from(this.ms.events).subscribe(v => {

   });

  }

}
```

my question is - if the events array aleady has elements in it, when the component is created, it will pick up all the existing elements, but what about elements that are added to the array after the subscription is created? How can I listen for when elements are added to the array after the fact?

If I use a `Subject`, the problem is I don't think it stores the historical items, just fires new ones.

Comment: looks like this question is similar -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466285/can-i-observe-additions-to-an-array-with-rx-js

Comment: I believe that I need to merge two different observables, but the caveat is that I need to read all the existing items in the array before receiving any new events from a Subject.

Comment: come to think of it, I think ReplaySubject is the one I am looking for that will re-broadcast previous values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @LLai has most of what you need, but I'd change `BehaviorSubject` to `ReplaySubject` and also change the emits to single events (given Alexander Mill's answer).

This doesn't cover removing events, although I don't see mention of that requirement.

**myService**

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  event$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();

  addEvent(event){
    this.event$.next(event);
  }
}
```

**myComponent**

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.mySub = this.ms.event$.subscribe(v => {
    ...
  });
}
```

**Demo**

```js
const replaySubject$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject(); 
// Also, pass in a buffer size to stop blow-out (if applicable)
// const replaySubject$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject(maxBufferSize); 


// Events before subscribe
replaySubject$.next('event1');
replaySubject$.next('event2');

replaySubject$.subscribe(console.log);

// Events after subscribe
replaySubject$.next('event3');
replaySubject$.next('event4');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would store the events within your service. This way the service can keep a history of all the events, and you can use the subject to emit that history.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    sub$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
    events: any[] = [];

    // add event to array and push to subject
    addEvent(event){
        this.events.push(event);
        this.sub$.next(this.events);
    }
    // find and remove event from array then push to subject
    removeEvent(event){
        let index = this.events.findIndex(item => {
            return event.id === item.id;
        });
        // if index is found, remove from array
        if(index !== -1){
            this.events.splice(index, 1);
            this.sub$.next(this.events);
        }
    }

}
```

I would use a behavior subject so the observers that subscribe receive the last emission (could also use a replay subject).

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/llai-behavior-subject?file=app%2Fmy-service.service.ts) demoing this

Comment: FYI, the following can be simplifed:

Comment: `sub$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);`

Comment: can just become this:

Comment: `sub$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);`

Comment: the former really pains me tbh

Comment: @AlexanderMills fair enough, you still get the typecasting with the simplified version

Comment: can you please demonstrate how a component would consume this service? it's not clear

Comment: ok nvm, i see it in the stackblitz. so can you compare this to my solution? To me, my answer seems simpler.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I think this solution provides a cleaner way for a component to access the events. It is simply a subscribe, not from + concat. The from + concat is somewhat mimicking what a behavior subject or replay subject would do.

Comment: @AlexanderMills In this solution, the service is responsible for storing the events, compiling the events, and broadcasting them. The component is only responsible for listening for the broadcast.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But I personally think mine is better. I tested my solution and it seems to work.

Comment: come to think of it, I think ReplaySubject is the one I am looking for that will re-broadcast previous values

Comment: @AlexanderMills yeah a ReplaySubject will replay the x amount of previous emissions. The only thing is you would push a single event to the subject, then when a component subscribes it will get each replay emission one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we merge two observables using the concat operator, and it seems to work. In essence, this answer is simply re-creating a ReplaySubject from scratch. Instead of using this answer, I'd recommend using a ReplaySubject instead. In any case:

*the service looks like this*

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {

   public subject = new Rx.Subject();
   public events = [];

   addItem(v: any){
    this.events.push(v);
    this.subject.next(v);
  }
}
```

*then the component looks like this*

```
@Inject(MyService)
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

  mySub: Subscriber

  constructor(private ms: MyService){}

  ngOnInit(){

    const obs = Rx.Observable.from(this.ms.events).concat(this.ms.subject);
    this.mySub = obs.subscribe(v => {

    });

  }

}
```

The idea is that the observable from the array is concatenated with the subject, and all the items from the array observable would fire first.

Comment: I think @LLai has the right principle of encapsulating all the observable parts in the service.

Comment: This `Rx.Observable.from(this.ms.events).concat(this.ms.subject)` looks a bit like your'e trying to do what `BehaviourSubject` or more likely `ReplaySubject` would do if you used one of those variants in your service. `Subject ... [does not] store the historical items` but ReplaySubject does.

Comment: Your use of `@Inject(MyService)` decorating the class looks novel. Any reference to this usage somewhere?

Comment: yeah idk, I am using Angular5, I was under the impression that using `@Inject` is what allows the service to be injected into the class instance, but maybe it can be omitted

Comment: @RichardMatsen yes you are right, I learned about ReplaySubject after creating this answer

Comment: I knew there had to be something built into the RxJS lib, because this seems like such a common use case

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about state, you should use a `Subject` which can be initialized with some data and later propagate.

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
   public events = [];
   public data$: Subject<any>;

   constructor() {
     this.data$ = this.events;
   }

   addItem(v: any) {
     this.event.push(v);
     this.data$.next(this.event);
   }
}
```

Then in your component if you want to have a live feed of data.

```
@Component({//usual angular stuff here})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myData: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myData = this.myService.data$;
  }
}
```

You can then use either the `async` pipe or subscribe to `myData` to get your data.

Comment: The service acts like a store, which produces your data, in your component you just subscribe or let angular do it for you. Any new events added will automatically trickle.

Comment: This `this.data$ = this.events` is going to break your observable property.