# RxJS from array - observe an array and write to console when changes?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is it possible for .subscribe to regularly listen to an array and its elements, and console.log new ones whenever they are being pushed on to the array?

Here are some code that i was experimenting with

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arraySource = from(arr);
//output: 1,2,3,4,5

let subscribe = arraySource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

setTimeout(() => {
  arr.push(6);
},2000);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want the entire array? or last item you have pushed?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `arr` and `arr$` aren't "connected". Once you subscribe to `arr$`, the elements originally in `arr` are emitted and then the observable completes. Further pushes to `arr` won't go through `arr$`:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const arr$ = from(arr);
arr$.subscribe(n => console.log(`n=${n}`));
arr.push(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {from} = rxjs;</script>
```

You should probably have a look at `Subject` and push data with `next()`.

However if you don't care about `arr` and just want to use `push()` as a mean to push data through an observable, then there's a hacky way. I would personally not do that but I'll show this for demonstration purpose:

```js
const arr = [];
const arr$ = fromEventPattern(handler => arr.push = handler);

arr$.subscribe(n => console.log(`n=${n}`));

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => arr.push(i++), 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {fromEventPattern} = rxjs;</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd need to use `observable.next()` like so:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arraySource = from(arr);
//output: 1,2,3,4,5

let subscribe = arraySource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

setTimeout(() => {
  arraySource.next(6);
},2000);
```

And perhaps have another subscriber that updates array?

Comment: Wouldn't `arraySource` complete after emitting `1` ... `5`?

Comment: oh yeah, you're right, you may want to try `Rx.Subject()` details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466285/can-i-observe-additions-to-an-array-with-rx-js